# JDBC Hibernate - Mysql Connection Error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, ubuntu-11.10

I have a local mysql server on my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop. The hostname = localhost; username = root; password = root; database name = CBS. I am really confused because when I access mysql using `terminal`, `mysql administrator`, and `mysql query browser` I use those authentication I mentioned above and everything is OK. My problem is when I configure my jdbc.properties in my Java App I'm getting this error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [28000]; error code [1045]; Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root    '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My configuration file, jdbc.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CBS
jdbc.username=root  
jdbc.password=root
```

By the way, the reason I will be using local server because our main server shutdown so I have to use my local mysql to continue with my project. Please help me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your hostname when using mysql adminstrator (or the other tools)?  As duffymo mentioned below you may have a grant issue with that user connecting to localhost.  I didn't see any mention about the hostname in the first part of your message.

Comment: do you run your "java app" using root creds ? when youy app runs - check it out using "ps -ef | grep <java app name>" and see which user is running it - in case it's not "root" you have your answer right there.

Answer (score 5):

More than likely your framework is logging into your local database as `127.0.0.1`. Which will create a login problem in MySQL if you have not defined an appropriate domain scoped credential. Try this to verify:

```
mysql -uroot -proot
SELECT * from mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';
```

If there is no 'root'@'127.0.0.1' then have found the problem and to remedy it, do one of two things:

1. Define a domain scoped credential for 'root', at '127.0.0.1'.
2. Define a wildcard domain scoped credential for 'root', so you can
   login to your MySQL with those credentials from multiple locations.

Here's an example of the second:

```
mysql -uroot -proot

CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

On a side note, I would definitely recommend using something more creative for your user id and password. Especially if you have TCP sockets enabled for your server.

Comment: When I ran the command SELECT * from users WHERE user = 'root'; what database will I use to see if I have a 'root'@'127.0.0.1'? Im new to this.

Comment: Actually, the command is `select * from mysql.user where user = 'root';`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I saw a lot of random characters like '+' and '-'. However I saw this line: | localhost | root | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B | Y           | Y. Does it mean I have a root?

Comment: Eh, do me a favor and execute this in mysql `select user, host from user`, and tell me how many rows show up with user 'root', and what the host field for the rows are.

Comment: I have 8 rows. I saw user = root and host = localhost.

Comment: Well, assuming you didn't see 'root' and host = '127.0.0.1', execute the solution I showed in my answer.

Comment: Im sorry but actually I saw it. username = root and host = 127.0.0.1. Is 127.0.0.1 the same with localhost? Anyway I saw both.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7771/discussion-between-ninjaboy-and-perception)

Answer (score 3):

You might have to GRANT permissions to access the database.

Look at the MySQL docs for something that looks like this:

```
create database pmt;
create user pmt identified by 'pmt';
grant all on pmt.* to 'pmt'@'%';
```

"pmt" is just an example above.  I happened to make the name of the database, username, and password all the same.  I don't recommend that as a best practice.  It's just something I did for some local development.

I personally don't like GRANTing root access to any application.  I would not use root username and password in even a toy application.  It doesn't take much effort to create a new user and GRANT appropriate permissions.

Comment: Do I have to restart my server after executing those commands?